# Convert Objective-C to Swift for these below code

Tags: objective-c, swift, converters

I tried to convert this Objective C code to Swift-4 using the online Convertor, But someHow failed to do that,

```
typedef void (^ActionBlock)();

## interface of custom class ##

@interface UIBlockButton : UIButton {
     ActionBlock _actionBlock;
}

## implementation of custom class ##

@implementation UIBlockButton

    -(void) handleControlEvent:(UIControlEvents)event
             withBlock:(ActionBlock) action {

        _actionBlock = Block_copy(action);
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(callActionBlock:) forControlEvents:event];

    }

    -(void) callActionBlock:(id)sender{
        _actionBlock();
    }

    -(void) dealloc{
        Block_release(_actionBlock);
        [super dealloc];
    }

@end
```

**This was the Output for swift code** ::: https://ibb.co/fRZFP7

Comment: Have you tried using Swiftify?

Comment: yes but its code not working properly

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code conversion service. What have you tried so far? Without showing some actual effort (not just stating that an online converter didn't work) you're highly unlikely to receive an answer. At least include the generated Swift code along with any raised compiler/runtime errors or a description of how it's not working as expected.

Comment: https://ibb.co/fRZFP7 . you can see these

Comment: @sejalthesiya never include code as a screenshot in your question. Include it as text using proper text formatting along with the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
typealias ActionBlock = () -> Void

class UIBlackButton: UIButton {

    var actionBlock: ActionBlock = {}

    func handleControlEvent(event: UIControlEvents, action:  @escaping ActionBlock) {
        actionBlock = action
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callActionBlock), for: event)
    }

    @objc func callActionBlock(sender: Any) {
        actionBlock();
    }  
}
```